# How to set a custom progress bar visibility state during an AppWidget update

Tags: android

Good day, ok, so i have no idea what am doing wrong here again. i wanted to show an AnimatedDrawable on my progressbar when updating my Appwidget and when i finish updating, i want the progress bar to become invisible. I know you have to embed the progress bar in a linearlayout or framelayout and call SetVisibility method of the remoteView on the layout. However, it doesn't seem to work. The progressbar keeps being visible and i don't know how to hide it anymore. what can i do?

to keep it short, i have a code like this to update the progressbar from the remoteview, i have intentionally left the comments there so you know what i have tried:

```
remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.linear_progressbar_container, View.INVISIBLE);
    animateProgressBar(remoteView);


private RemoteViews animateProgressBar(RemoteViews remoteView) {
         Resources res = context.getResources();
//AnimationDrawable drawable = (AnimationDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.my_animation);
         //drawable.setOneShot(false);
         //drawable.start();

         //remoteView.setProgressBar(R.id.progress_widget_id, 0, 0, true);

         Log.d(TAG, "calling setview indeterminate");
       remoteView.setViewVisibility(R.id.linear_progressbar_container, View.INVISIBLE);

            return remoteView;
        }
```

and in my xml layout, i have this portion with the progress bar, this is inside a relative layout which is the root with other textviews in it:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/city_id"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/image_id"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_id"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/linear_progressbar_container">    

        <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress_widget_id">    
        </ProgressBar>     

        </LinearLayout>
```

the drawable my_animation.xml:

```
 <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:visible="false" android:oneshot="true">

     <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />"

    </animation-list>
```

please help.. :(  how do i make this progress bar become visible and invisible during and after i update my AppWidget respectively? Thank you for the time and all your help.

Note: I do all widget updating via a service.

Answer (score 0):

You should Have a service update the app widget's RemoteViews when sufficient time has elapsed to make it worthwhile to update.

Comment: yes i use an alarm manager to update the AppWidget via the service. What am saying is that i am having trouble setting the appropriate visibility of the progress bar via the remoteview. it should be present when updating and invisible when it finishes updating.